# List of functions

Tags: functions

Help me please. If I have a list of functions:

```
fun = {x^2+1, x+5, x^3};
```

Can I make a function from a list item? For example, f[x_]:=x^2+1.

Comment: try `f[x_] := fun[[1]]`?

Comment: @kglr, it isn't function :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAl[[f]
f[x_] := fun[[1]]

{f[u], f[5]}
```

> { 1 + u^2, 26}

You can also define three pure functions from `fun`:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3]
{f1, f2, f3} = Function[x, #] & /@ fun;

{f1[t], f1[5]}
```

> { 1 + t^2, 26}

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[g1, g2, g3]
{g1[x_], g2[x_], g3[x_]} := Evaluate @ fun;

{g1[y], g2[q], g3[s], g1[5], g2[5], g3[5]}
```

> {1 + y^2, 5 + q, s^3, 26, 10, 125}

Comment: sorry me, the last question, how I can do this for a list of arbitrary length?

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: @GThompson, in the first approach replace `{f1,f2,f3}` on the lhs  with `Evaluate[Array[Symbol["f" <> ToString@#] &, Length@fun]]` and in the second approach replace `{g1,g2,g3}` on the lhs with `Evaluate[Array[Symbol["g" <> ToString@#][x_] &, Length@fun]]`

Answer (score 4):

```
fun = {x^2 + 1, x + 5, x^3};
```

I don't think you really want to define `f` as

```
f[x_]:=fun[[1]]
```

If you look at the Global symbol `f` after making this definition it shows up as:

```
?f
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It works but there are two caveats:

1. You get the expected answer only as long as `fun` remains unchanged.
2. Each time you run it there is an extra evaluations step (i.e., fun[[1]] gets replaced with `1 + x^5`) and then that is evaluated.

Below is a `Trace` of `f[x]`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I think it is more productive to define `f` as

```
f[x_] := Evaluate[fun[[1]]]
```

Now when we look at the Global symbol `f` one sees:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

After the definition is made `f` is no longer dependent on `fun`.

Further it requires fewer evaluation steps.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

This is an example where you shd use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed`.

```
ClearAll[f, x]
fun = {x^2 + 1, x + 5, x^3};
f[x_] := fun[[1]]
DownValues[f]  (* {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> fun[[1]]} *)
ClearAll[f, x]
fun = {x^2 + 1, x + 5, x^3};
f[x_] = fun[[1]]
DownValues[f]   (* {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> 1 + x^2} *)
```